# Converting memory utilization data to graph in linux

Tags: gnuplot

I have made a bash script in which i am using sar command to get the memory utilization and than the data to .txt file on the time and the percentage utilization.
Than through gnuplot trying to convert the data to graph but when m doing it graph is not showing proper data like if i have data from morning 9 to 4pm data in graph shows only till 1pm and graph is also horizontal and not starting from 0. I want graph to be vertically and lines connecting to each other with full time data

Comment: You're gonna have to provide a _lot_ more information for anyone to be able to help you here.  Data collection, gnuplot files, more...